# Area under a curve

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that when given five integers as input, outputs the value given by the following integral:

[image]

- Input is five integers (in any reasonable format) in the order `a b c d e` where each number corresponds to the variables in the image above.
- No built in integral functions allowed.
- Output must be a base ten float, precise to `+/- 1e-3`.

Least number of bytes wins.

Comment: Why would you want to use a built-in integral function? It's just printing out an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @feersum A built-in integral function might give an unfair advantage

Comment: Hard to believe an integral function is unfairly advantageous compared to finding the difference of ax^3/3+bx^2/2+cx at two points.

Comment: @feersum Well, it's there as a rule just in case :)

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: Apparently many people agree that Input: x,y Output: 3x + 5y is too boring to be good question.

Comment: @feersum Mm.. I'll keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: I'm just near the Naruto hat if you didn't upvote...

Comment: @user23013 I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 27 bytes

```
q~W%2/~~[2*\~3*\6*0]fb:-6d/
```

Example input:

```
[1 2 3 4 8]
```

Output:

```
209.33333333333334
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
l~\:D-A3#:K*),])\f{\dK/D+\~\Z$*+@_*@*+K/}:+
```

The arguments are read via STDIN like

```
1 2 3 4 7
```

and the output is printed to STDOUT like

```
135.04650050000018
```

You can increase the precision by changing the `3` in `A3#:K` to a higher number. The higher the number, the longer the program will take to finish.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 71 bytes

If the input is a vector `x <- c(a, b, c, d, e)` then you can compute the integral directly as per @feersum's comment.

```
e=x[5];d=x[4];x[1]*e^3/3+x[2]*e^2/2+x[3]*e-x[1]*d^3/3-x[2]*d^2/2-x[3]*d
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 52 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d,e)=>a*e^3/3+b*e^2/2+c*e-a*d^3/3-b*d^2/2-c*d
```

Calculates the indefinite integral at `e` and `d`, then subtract.